# setting an integer value in a textbox according to the option selected from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I want set an integer value in a textbox depending upon the option selected from a dropdown menu . Each option in a dropDown will set a different value in a textbox . Here is my code . Waitng for helpful answers .

```
<html>

    <head>

        <script>

    function myfunction(val)
    {
            var x=document.getElementById('ops');

            var y=document.getElementById('text');

            var z=document.getElementById('lb');
            //if(val='pepsi')

                z.style.display = "block";

                y.style.display = "Inline";

                }

        function setval(data)
        {


            var b=document.getElementById('ops');
            var a=document.getElementById('txtprice');

            if (data.value='pepsi')
                {
                var c='50';
                a.value=parseInt(c);    
            }
            else if(data.value='fanta') 
                {

                a.value=parseInt(12);

                }
        // other options 
        }


    function myfun2()
            {
            var c=document.getElementById("lb1");

            var b=document.getElementById("btn1");

            var a=document.getElementById('dte');

            b.style.display="block";

            c.style.display="block";

            a.style.display="block";
            }

    function validateform()
        {

        var n = document.getElementById("text");

    if(n.value==null || n.value==" ")
        {
        alert("please enter any val.");

            return false;
        }
    else
    {

        a = isNaN(n.value);
    //return ( ! isNaN(n.value));

    if(a==true)
    {
        alert ("Characters are not allowed :( ");

        return false;
    }
    else

        return true;    
    }
        }

            </script>


        </head>

<body>

 <form name='mform' action="process.php"  onSubmit="return validateform()">

        <select id="ops" onChange="setval(this)">

                        <option>PIck item </option>
                        <option value="pepsi">pepsi</option>
                        <option value="coke">coke</option>
                        <option value="fanta">Fanta</option>

        </select><br><br>


    <label id="lb" style="display:none" >Qty</label>

    <input type="text" name='qtytext' id="text" style="display:none" onKeyUp="return validateform()" on onSelect="return validateform()" onFocus="myfun2()" required/ >


    <label id="lb1" style="display:none" >.....Before proceeding, Make sure that form is properly filled.....</label>

    <input type="submit" name'btn' id='btn1' value="Submit" style='display:none' /> <br>

    <input type="date" name="dte" id='dte' style="display:none" onKeyUp="return validateform()"  onFocus="myfun2()">

    <input type="text" name'txt' id='txtprice' /> <br>

</form>

        </body>

                </html>
```

Comment: What happens with that code ? Please give us some hints on what fails so one can help you (edit the question).

Comment: for one, you should be setting the textbox value to a string, not an int.  (a.value=parseInt(c); should be: a.value='50';)  And you txtprice input has incorrect html.  Should be name='txt'.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error on your textbox input.  It should be (you're missing an = sign on name):

```
<input type="text" name='txt' id='txtprice' />
```

Also, you should pass a string to the textbox, not an int.  So, for example, change this:

```
a.value=parseInt(c);
```

To this:

```
a.value = '50';
```

UPDATE (updated fiddle link as well):

You also are assigning the values in your condition, rather than evaluating them.  For example:

```
if (data.value='pepsi')
```

Should be:

```
if (data.value=='pepsi')
```

NOTE:  I only evaluated the portion of code that addresses the specific question asked by the OP, and did not look for issues in other areas of the code.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/339nk9n0/2/) Demo

Comment: And there are more errors. For instance `if (data.value='pepsi')` assigns "pepsi" to data.value, even if it's in an `if`. I'm not sure the code is salvageable without a complete rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8m18d74L/1/) of how you can achieve this. You might need to change it a bit to fit your script, but this will show you the basics of how you can change the value in a textbox from a dropdown.

Basically:

**HTML**

```
<select id="sel">
   <option value="50">Pepsi</option>
   <option value="100">Fanta</option>
   <option value="150">Cola</option>
</select>    
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#sel').on('change', function() {
   $('#txt').val($(this).val());
});
```

If you prefer to use plain Javascript over jQuery, just replace the jQuery script above with:

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("sel").onchange = function(){
   document.getElementById("txt").value = this.value;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8m18d74L/2/)